# Handling 404 in tide

Tags: http, rust

So let's say I am making a web app with tide in rust, and I want to serve a 404 page when the user goes somewhere that does not exist. Currently it just gives a blank page. How can i do that? I know `app.at(...)` but there is nothing like `app.not_found(...)`.
Is there any simple way to do this that doesn't require middleware? I have looked at middleware but it seems quite complex. If middleware is needed, how could I use it? It is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look into the documentation of tide and search for a wildcard
https://docs.rs/tide/latest/tide/struct.Server.html

By defining the wildcard route at the end this will handled all of the unexpected routes

```rust
use tide::Request;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> tide::Result<()> {
    let mut app = tide::new();
    app.at("/hello").get(handle_expected);
    app.at("*").get(handle_unexpected);
    app.listen("0.0.0.0:8080").await?;
    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_expected(req: Request<()>) -> tide::Result {
    Ok("OK".into())
}

async fn handle_unexpected(req: Request<()>) -> tide::Result {
    Ok("404".into())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wildcard pattern `*` to match all routes.

Then you just need to add the routes in the correct order (e.g. your custom 404-handler must be last).

Here is a full example:

```rust
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let mut app = tide::new();

    app.at("/").get(|_| async { Ok("Hello, world!") });
    app.at("*").get(|_| async { Ok("Not found") });
    app.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

using these dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
tide = "0.16.0"
async-std = { version = "1.8.0", features = ["attributes"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```